# javascript in href not working?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I just developed a web app for mobiles.
everything is fine except this: there is a link  with javascript in its href.
it works in all the browsers( chrome, firefox, ...) but it doesn't work in mobiles.
the issue appeared in Samsung devices.
How could I debug that?

Comment: 1. You didn't say which mobile browsers you're experiencing this issue with; 2. The problem is most likely with the code that you're executing, which you also didn't include in the question.

Comment: The `href` attribute is not designed for javascript. The `href` attribute should point to another resource on the web. Use the `onclick` event to handle any javascript that should trigger when clicking the anchor.

Comment: I'm using Opera Mobile Emulator for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use remote debugging with chrome, as [explained here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=de) - this way, you get a developer console on your PC which displays the console and dom tree of your smartphone chrome.

However, as already suggested in the comments: Don't use *javascript:* in href - use event handler and bind them to the click event:

```
$("#mylink").on("click", function()
{
    alert("i'm clicked");
});
```